# getchar waiting for input (enter) before continuing

Tags: c, getchar

I have a function that wants to get user input, and keeps asking for user input until 2 or 3 is entered. A small problem I have right now is that after entering 2 or 3 and pressing Enter, I need to press Enter again before it continues with the next part of the program. Is it even possible to use getchar and not encounter this problem? I haven't been able to find an adequate solution

```
int getPlayersNumber() {
    int numberOfPlayers;
    do {
        printf("\nHow many players will be playing ? (2 or 3) ");
        scanf("%d", &numberOfPlayers);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
    } while (numberOfPlayers != 2 && numberOfPlayers != 3);

    printf("\n");
    flushInput();

    return numberOfPlayers;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I have the problem now that when entering nothing and just pressing enter, the program gets stuck in this method

Comment: Your response to any of the answers has been almost zero.  Have you tried looking at any of them?

Answer (score 0):

Use getchar on the onset to read 2 or 3 instead of scanf.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your problem, i didn't put `flushInput` since i don't know what it come from. But I didn't encounter your problem. I think the `while (getchar() != '\n');` is enough to solve your problem. This problem may be caused by other part of program, can you paste whole code?

Comment: seems like flushInput was causing the problem I had. I oversaw it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code depends on what value `numberOfPlayers` is when starting. Because it is not initialized, there is no way to tell what will happen.

Change this:

```
int getPlayersNumber() {
    int numberOfPlayers;//not initialized
```

To this:

```
int getPlayersNumber() {
    int numberOfPlayers == 0;//not == 2 or 3
```

And there is no need for whatever `flushInput` is doing.  If it is defined to call `fflush(stdin);` it is likely undefined behavior.

Your code worked fine for me with edits shown below:

```
int getPlayersNumber(void) {
    int numberOfPlayers = 0;
    do {
        printf("\nHow many players will be playing ? (2 or 3) ");
        scanf("%d", &numberOfPlayers);
        //while (getchar() != '\n');
    } while (numberOfPlayers != 2 && numberOfPlayers != 3);

    printf("\n");
    //flushInput();

    return numberOfPlayers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'scanf' for interactive input is a common mistake. There are many questions related to this in SO - see below for common alternative, using fgets, as mentioned in comment by user3121023.

```
int getPalyersNumber () {
  char work[64] ;
  while ( fgets(work, sizeof(work), stdin) != NULL ) {
    int numberOfPlayers ;
    if ( sscanf(work, "%d", &numberOfPlayers) == 1 ) {
      if ( numberOfPlayers == 2 || numberOfPlayers == 3 ) {
         return numberOfPlayers ;
      }    
    } ;
    fprintf(stderr, "Bad Input!\n") ;
  } ;
  perror("Error Reading Data") ;
  abort() ;
}
```

Possible to customize the error handling - but some corrective action is needed when `fgets` return NULL - not possible to retry reading. Simple retry will put the code into infinite spin on EOF, or other errors.